# Counting how many functions exist given a relation

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, relations

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and let $F$ be the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$. Let $S$ be the relation on $F$ defined by:

$\forall f, g \in F$, $fSg \iff f(i) = g(i)$ for some $i \in A$

Let $h: A \to A$ be the function defined by $h(x) = 1$ for all $x \in A$ How many functions $g \in F$ are there so that $gSh$?

So for whatever $x \in A$, $h(x) = 1$. So I want to find how many functions $g \in F$ exist so that $gSh$.

So I made a sort of "recipe" for counting how many functions $g$ exist. Since in order for $gSh$, $g(i) = 1$ for any $i \in A$, since $g(i) = h(i)$ if $gSh$.

Step 1: Map $1 \to 1$

Step 2: Map $2 \to 1$

Step 3: Map $3 \to 1$

Step 4: Map $4 \to 1$

So this is just equal to $1 * 1 * 1 * 1$. So my assumption is that there exists only $1$ function $g$ such that $gSh$. Is this correct? I think I might be misunderstanding the wording, and just want to make sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've misunderstood. The function $q$ defined by $[1 \to 3, 2 \to 4, 3\to 1, 4\to 4]$, for instance, is in the set, because for some $i \in A$ (namely, for $i = 3$), we have $q(i) = 1 = h(i)$, so $q S h$.

Comment: No...the relation holds when $f(i)=g(i)$ even once.  Thus, for instance, the function $g(i)=i$ satisfies $g\,S\,h$.

Comment: Hint: I think it's easier to count the functions which  aren't related to $h$ under $S$, and subtract that figure from the total number of functions.

Comment: @lulu Would i be correct in saying that there are $(81)$ ways in which $g(i)$ does not  relate to $h(i)$, So $(4 * 4 * 4 * 4)$ - $81$ = $175$ ways?

Comment: Absolutely right.